# action only applied when intersection occurs but not afterward

Tags: ios

I am making a single view game demo, and i am disabling a button when two frames intersect. but when the character gets out of the intersection, that disabling is still stuck. how can i limit the button to be disabled only on intersection, and not afterward?

```
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainchar.frame, breakablewalla.frame)) {
    if (grainscount == 0) {
        right.enabled = NO;
    }
    if (grainscount >= 1) {
        right.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your code, I can only assume you want something like this:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainchar.frame, breakablewalla.frame))
{
    right.enabled = grainscount > 0 ? YES : NO;
}
else
{
    right.enabled = YES;
}
```